# Use FeatureTools on specific columns only

Tags: python, featuretools

I am trying to use feature tools to generate some new features using only some specified columns for the Titanic dataset. In my case I want to do a transform 'add_numeric' and 'multiply_numeric' on Age, Pclass and log10splitfare. I have followed the syntax given [here](https://docs.featuretools.com/en/stable/generated/featuretools.dfs.html?highlight=featuretools) to the best of my knowledge but no avail. The code below does not error out but it does not produce any additional columns. I also used this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52418152/featuretools-can-it-be-applied-on-a-single-table-to-generate-features-even-when)  as a reference.

```
es = ft.EntitySet(id = 'Titanic')
es.entity_from_dataframe(entity_id = 'data', dataframe = ftdataset_cleaned, 
                         make_index = False, index = 'index')

# Run deep feature synthesis with transformation primitives
feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(entityset = es, target_entity = 'data',
                                      trans_primitives = ['add_numeric', 'multiply_numeric'],
                                      primitive_options= {('add_numeric', 'multiply_numeric'):{"include_entities": ['Age','PClass','log10SplitFare']}}
                                      )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `include_variables` option to specify which columns in an entity to use for specific primitives

```py
feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(
    entityset=es,
    target_entity='data',
    trans_primitives=['add_numeric', 'multiply_numeric'],
    primitive_options={
        ('add_numeric', 'multiply_numeric'): {
            'include_variables': {'data': ['Age', 'PClass', 'log10SplitFare']}}})
```

[This guide](https://docs.featuretools.com/en/stable/guides/specifying_primitive_options.html) goes a little more in depth about the different ways you can control how primitives are applied.

Comment: This doesn't work if the primitive is custom made